# on google drive, does folder exist always returns false

Tags: function, google-apps-script, boolean, google-drive-api, directory

I am using google app scripts to create a folder on the google drive. I don't want any duplication on the drive so I created a function to find out if the folder exists.

I am putting all the folder names into an array and then seeing if the folder name exists in that array. It always returns false though...

Can you see where I've gone wrong here? or is there a better method of finding out if a folder exists on the drive or not??

```
function doesContainerExist(container) {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var Folders = new Array;
  var boolean;

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    Folders.push(folders.next());
  }

  if(Folders.indexOf(container) == -1) {
    boolean = false;
  } else {
    boolean = true;
  }
  Logger.log(container);

  return boolean;

};
```

Answer (score 7):

There is another efficient way to check if a folder already exist, here is the code with a testfunction for you to try :

```
function testTest(){
  Logger.log(testFolder('Photos'));// returns true if folder exists, false if it doesn't
}

function testFolder(folderName){
  var exist = true;
  try{var testFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName)}
  catch(err){exist=false}
  return exist;
}
```

Since your final purpose is to create a folder you can create it directly inside the 'catch' part of the script or simply integrate the try/catch in your existing code you use to create the folder.

Comment: Ok that was almost too simple. I had a try catch in a function before I found that the code would stop running after the try function didn't execute, so it was the exact same as your example. I didn't realize that it would work in its own function. Thanks for your help Serge

Comment: This function 'testFolder' seems to be unreliable. You can't pass a variable into a catch so exist=false will not work. I think I can improve on your method though 

`function doesFolderExist(folderName) {
  var exists = true;
  try{var testFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
      
      if(typeof testFolder == 'folder') {
        return exists;
      }
     }
  catch(err){var exist=false
  return exist;
            }
  
};`

Comment: what do you mean by "unreliable" ? a script works or does not, unreliable would mean sometimes it does sometimes not... IMO in this case it simply works.

Comment: sorry that probably came across as condescending, I was looking at the code this morning and it looked like it wouldn't work because of the variable exists. Your right it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for Strings only, while you are trying to search through Folder objects.

```
function doesContainerExist(container) {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var Folders = new Array();
  var boolean;

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    Folders.push(folders.next().getName());
  }

  if(Folders.indexOf(container) == -1) {
    boolean = false;
  } else {
    boolean = true;
  }
  Logger.log(container);

  return boolean;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function checks if a path exists or not. If not, it creates it. The passed parameter `path` is a string that looks like (for instance):
`var path = "//Main Folder/Subfolder 1/Subfolder 2";`
If you want to create this directory, call `createDirectory(path)`.

```
function createDirectory(path) {

  var name, folder, search, fullpath;

  // Remove slashes and trim the path
  fullpath = path.replace(/^\/*|\/*$/g, '').split("/");

  // start with the main folder
  folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

  for (var subfolder in fullpath) {

    name = fullpath[subfolder];
    search = folder.getFoldersByName(name);

    // If folder in current level does not exit, create it
    folder = search.hasNext() ? search.next() : folder.createFolder(name);        
  }      
  return folder;      
}
```

Line `folder = search.hasNext() ? search.next() : folder.createFolder(name);` can be replaced by:

```
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}
```

If you just would like to check if directory exists, you need to omit `folder.createFolder(name);` from the loop and `return false` instead.